# $\LaTeX$ format copy problem

Tags: latex

I need to write a $\LaTeX$ document from my functions developed in Mathematica. When I try to get a $\LaTeX$ form of the following integral

[image: screenshot]

```
TexForm[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(4  \[Pi]\)]\(
\*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)] \((
\*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\[CenterDot]A)\) \
\[DifferentialD]\[Omega]\)\) = (4 \[Pi])/3 A]
```

I get an error.

```
During evaluation of In[2]:= Set::write: Tag Integrate in \!\(\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(4\ \[Pi]\)]\(\(\*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\[CenterDot]A\ \*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)]\) \[DifferentialD]\[Omega]\)\) is Protected.

Out[2]= TexForm[(4 A \[Pi])/3]
```

Comment: Replace `=` with `==`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your equation gets evaluated to the right-hand side.  Avoid that thus:

```
TeXForm[HoldForm[\!\(
\*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(4  \[Pi]\)]\(
\*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)] \((
\*OverscriptBox[\(s\), \(\[RightVector]\)] + 
       A)\) \[DifferentialD]\[Omega]\)\) = (4 \[Pi])/3 A]]
```

Also... remember the capital X in `TeXForm`!